# How to write data to local DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

According to DynamoDB docs, you always need to specify `--endpoint-url http://localhost:8000` option if you want to interact with your local (downloaded) version of DynamoDB. It works fine for me via `aws cli`, but, following their tutorial for Node.js developers, I've faced a strange issue: **I have been interacting with data in DynamoDB web version instead of my local one, even if configured connection options to database**:

```
  const serviceConfigOptions: ServiceConfigurationOptions = {
    region: "eu-north-1",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
  };
```

I described endpoint, but I have no results interacting with data in my local version and I have these in the web.
All code is here:

```
import fs from "fs";

import AWS, { AWSError } from "aws-sdk";
import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";

import {
  CreateTableInput,
  DocumentClient,
  PutItemInput,
  PutItemOutput,
} from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";
import { ServiceConfigurationOptions } from "aws-sdk/lib/service";

dotenvConfig();

const serviceConfigOptions: ServiceConfigurationOptions = {
  region: "eu-north-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
};

const dynamoDB: AWS.DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const params: CreateTableInput = {
  TableName: "Movies",
  KeySchema: [
    {
      AttributeName: "year",
      KeyType: "HASH",
    },
    {
      AttributeName: "title",
      KeyType: "RANGE",
    },
  ],
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
    { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" },
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10,
  },
};

dynamoDB.createTable(params, (err, data): void => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to create table.");
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Table created");
  console.log(data);
});

const docClient: DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Imporing data to DynamoDB");
fs.readFile(
  "moviedata.json",
  "utf-8",
  (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, data: string): void => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Unable to read a file");
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    const allMovies: Array<any> = JSON.parse(data);

    allMovies.forEach(({ year, title, info }): void => {
      const params: PutItemInput = {
        TableName: "Movies",
        Item: {
          year,
          title,
          info,
        },
      };

      docClient.put(params, (err: AWSError, data: PutItemOutput) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(
            "Unable to add movie",
            title,
            ". Error JSON:",
            JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),
          );
          return;
        }
        console.log("PutItem succeeded:", title);
      });
    });
  },
);
```

**UPDATE:**
Refactored code into promises.

```
import fs from "fs";
import { promisify } from "util";

import AWS, { AWSError } from "aws-sdk";
import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";

import {
  CreateTableInput,
  DocumentClient,
  PutItemInput,
  PutItemOutput,
} from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";
import { ServiceConfigurationOptions } from "aws-sdk/lib/service";

dotenvConfig();

const serviceConfigOptions: ServiceConfigurationOptions = {
  region: "eu-north-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
};

const dynamoDB: AWS.DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const params: CreateTableInput = {
  TableName: "Movies",
  KeySchema: [
    {
      AttributeName: "year",
      KeyType: "HASH",
    },
    {
      AttributeName: "title",
      KeyType: "RANGE",
    },
  ],
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
    { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" },
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10,
  },
};

const createDBTable: (
  params: AWS.DynamoDB.CreateTableInput,
) => Promise<AWS.DynamoDB.CreateTableOutput> = promisify(
  dynamoDB.createTable,
).bind(dynamoDB);

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

createDBTable(params)
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Table created");
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Unable to create table.");
    throw new Error(err);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Imporing data to DynamoDB");
    return readFile("moviedata.json", "utf-8");
  })
  .then((data: string) => {
    const allMovies: Array<any> = JSON.parse(data);
    const docClient: DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    allMovies.forEach(({ year, title, info }): void => {
      const params: PutItemInput = {
        TableName: "Movies",
        Item: {
          year,
          title,
          info,
        },
      };

      docClient.put(params, (err: AWSError, data: PutItemOutput) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(
            "Unable to add movie",
            title,
            ". Error JSON:",
            JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),
          );
          return;
        }
        console.log("PutItem succeeded:", title);
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Now I'm getting `Unable to create table. Error: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists: Movies`. However, in my local db only one `Music` table.

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Out:

```
{
    "TableNames": [
        "Music"
    ]
}
```

P.S. `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

Comment: Wait for the table is already created then, insert data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake I made.
I've configured params

```
const serviceConfigOptions: ServiceConfigurationOptions = {
  region: "eu-north-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
};
```

but I forgot to pass it to `const dynamoDB: AWS.DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();` as an argument.

Must be

```
const serviceConfigOptions: ServiceConfigurationOptions = {
  region: "eu-north-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
};
const dynamoDB: AWS.DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB(serviceConfigOptions);
```